# Bootstrap modal only closes for one click. If reopen modal and click again will not close

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. When I click on a image in my modal the bootstrap modal should close and reset.

I use codeigniter pagination when I click on a image on the first page it closes modal fine. How ever if I reopen modal and click on another pagination page then click on image will not close modal does not refresh modal

> **Question** how can I make sure bootstrap modal will close for every image
>   I click on. When I reopen model and click another image bootstrap modal
>   won't close

Script

```
$('.modal-body a img').on("click", function(){
    $('#mySmile').modal('hide');
});
```

Script

```
<!-- #mYSmile div is appended when click on button -->

<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <?php echo smiley_js();?>
    <?php foreach (array_chunk($smileys, 4) as $smiley) { ?>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <?php foreach ($smiley as $smile) {?>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <?php echo $smile['img'];?>  
    </div>
    <?php }?>
    </div>
    <?php }?>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <?php echo $pagination; ?>
    </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#mySmile .pagination a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mySmile').load($(this).attr('href'));
});

$('.modal-body a img').on("click", function(){
    $('#mySmile').modal('hide');
});
</script>
```

Common.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).delegate('button[id=\'smile-button\']', 'click', function() {

    $('#mySmile').remove();

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'smiley',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html) {
            $('body').append('<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="mySmile">' + html + '</div>');
            $('#mySmile').modal('show');
        }
    }); 

});
});
```

Controller Just encase any one ask for it.

```
<?php 

class Smiley extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('smiley');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

    public function index() {
        $results = get_clickable_smileys(base_url('assets/images/smileys/'), 'message');

        $files_count = count($results);

        // Set your displayed limit.
        $files_limit = 8;

        // The input get you could rename to a uri segment if not using query string
        $input_get_per_page = $this->input->get('per_page');
        $input_get_per_page += $files_limit;

        $data['smileys'] = array();

        foreach($results as $file => $value) {
            if ($file < $input_get_per_page && $file >= $input_get_per_page - $files_limit) {
                $data['smileys'][] = array(
                    'img' => $value
                );

            }   
        }

        $config['base_url'] = base_url('smiley') . '/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $files_count;
        $config['per_page'] = $files_limit;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['num_links'] = "5";
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] = "</ul>";
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
        $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->view('template/extensions/smiley', $data);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
$('.modal-body a img').on("click", function(){
    $('#mySmile').modal('hide');
});
```

to

```
$('.modal-body a img').on("click", function(){
    $('#mySmile').modal('hide');
    $('.modal').remove();
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
});
```

Also replace code in common.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).delegate('button[id=\'smile-button\']', 'click', function() {

    $('#mySmile').modal('hide');
    $('.modal').remove();
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'smiley',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html) {
            $('body').append('<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="mySmile">' + html + '</div>');
            $('#mySmile').modal('show');
        }
    }); 

});
});
```

Comment: Still same issue when I click on image once it closes but if reopen bs modal and click on another image will not close ./ hide / refresh modal.

Comment: Now when click button to open modal second time modal won't open.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$('.modal-body a img').on("click", function(){
    $('#mySmile').modal('hide');
});
```

**WITH**

```
$(document).on('click','.modal-body a img', function(){
    $('#mySmile').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: When I am on a click on my pagination link and select image won't close Closes on first page OK

Comment: I cannot post demo as its php and javascript

Comment: As again it mixed with php

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

I needed on my common.js remove $('#mySmile').remove();

And then create a refresh button then create a trigger

```
$('#button-refresh').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mySmile').load("<?php echo base_url('smiley');?>");
});

$('#mySmile .pagination a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mySmile').load($(this).attr('href'));
});

$('.modal-body a img').on("click", function(){
    $('#mySmile').modal('hide');
    $('#button-refresh').trigger('click');
});
```